# Oracle opening and closing balance - SQL or PL/SQL needed?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 select year, 
        month ,
        d.PROD_ID, 
        T.CUSTOMER_ID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN D.OP_TYPE = 1 THEN d.qty END)    EARNED,
        SUM(CASE WHEN D.OP_TYPE = 2 THEN d.qty END)    SPEND
FROM TXN_HEADER T  , 
     TXN_DETAIL d , 
     CUSTOMER A,
     PRODUCT e 
WHERE T.AMOUNT > 0 
AND   A.TYPE  =  0
AND   T.CUSTOMER_ID = A.CUSTOMER_ID
AND   T.TXN_PK = D.TXN_PK 
and   d.PROD_ID = e.PROD_ID
and   e.unit = 0
group by year, month ,d.PROD_ID, T.CUSTOMER_ID
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4
```

Output is as follows (here opening and closing not generated by query, but I required that has to be from the query)

```
YEAR MONTH PROD CUSTOMER OPENING EARNED SPEND CLOSING 
---- ----- ---- -------- ------- ------ ----- -------
2012     8  548    12033       0      8     2       6
2012     9  509    12033       0     24     0      24
2012     9  509    12047       0     14     0      14
2012     9  548    12033       6      1     0       7
2012     9  548    12047       0      1     0       1
```

I required to generate the output as above. Here PROD_ID,CUSTOMER_ID wise dynamically the prev closing balance to be populated as opening and it shoulde calculate closing balance (opening+earned-spend) monthwise,customer wise ,product wise. is it possible to write in SQL or need to go PL/SQL?

Comment: IS YOUR CAPS LOCK KEY STUCK? UN-STICK IT, PLEASE.

Comment: by mistake it was on .. sorry for the inconv.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use analytics, with PROD_ID and CUSTOMER_ID in the partition clause to avoid mixing products and customers.

```
WITH
MONTHLY_BALANCE AS
(
  SELECT
    YEAR,
    MONTH,
    D.PROD_ID,
    T.CUSTOMER_ID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.OP_TYPE = 1 THEN D.QTY ELSE NULL END) EARNED,
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.OP_TYPE = 2 THEN D.QTY ELSE NULL END) SPEND,
  FROM TXN_HEADER T
  JOIN CUSTOMER A 
  ON    T.CUSTOMER_ID = A.CUSTOMER_ID
  JOIN TXN_DETAIL D
  ON    T.TXN_PK = D.TXN_PK
  JOIN PRODUCT E
  ON    D.PROD_ID = E.PROD_ID
  WHERE T.AMOUNT > 0
  AND   A.TYPE = 0
  AND   E.UNIT = 0
  GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, D.PROD_ID, T.CUSTOMER_ID
)
SELECT
  YEAR,
  MONTH,
  PROD_ID,
  CUSTOMER_ID,
  SUM(NVL(EARNED, 0) - NVL(SPEND, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY PROD_ID, CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) OPENING,
  EARNED,
  SPEND,
  SUM(NVL(EARNED, 0) - NVL(SPEND, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY PROD_ID, CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT_ROW) CLOSING
FROM MONTHLY_BALANCE
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` needs an `ELSE`

```
CASE WHEN D.OP_TYPE = 1 THEN d.qty ELSE 0 END
```

Without the else the `CASE` will return `NULL` when `D.OP_TYPE` is not equal to `1`, and anything+`NULL`=`NULL`. When your `WHEN` is not satisfied it returns `NULL` and that is why you do not see anything for those columns.

To get OPENING and CLOSING calculated as you may want to use [analytic functions](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php) like `LEAD` and `LAG`.

```
Select year,month,prod_id,customer_id,
       LAG(closing,1,0) OVER (order by year,month,prod_id,customer_id) as opening,
       earned,spend
      ,(LAG(closing,1,0) OVER (order by year,month,prod_id,customer_id)+closing) as closing
from (WITH temp AS (select year, 
                           month ,
                           d.PROD_ID, 
                           T.CUSTOMER_ID,
                           0 OPEN,
                          SUM(CASE WHEN D.OP_TYPE = 1 THEN d.qty END)    EARNED,
                          SUM(CASE WHEN D.OP_TYPE = 2 THEN d.qty END)    SPEND,
                          0 CLOSE
                     FROM TXN_HEADER T  , 
                          TXN_DETAIL d , 
                          CUSTOMER A,
                          PRODUCT e 
                    WHERE T.AMOUNT > 0 
                      AND   A.TYPE  =  0
                      AND   T.CUSTOMER_ID = A.CUSTOMER_ID
                      AND   T.TXN_PK = D.TXN_PK 
                      and   d.PROD_ID = e.PROD_ID
                      and   e.unit = 0
                     group by year, month ,d.PROD_ID, T.CUSTOMER_ID
                     ORDER BY 1,2,3,4)
   SELECT year,month,prod_id,customer_id,open,earned,spend,(open+earned-spend) as closing
     from temp);
```

Comment: Purposly i left those columns blank , bcos i am not sure how to calculate those opening and closing runtime